# Laravel "Invalid route action: [C:32:\"Opis\\Closure\\Serializable Closure\"

Tags: laravel, api

I had this error `"Invalid route action: [C:32:\"Opis\\Closure\\Serializable Closure\"` while I was making a test closure function in the routes file and I have no clue what is going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked most of the answers and nothing satisfied my curiosity but due to my deadline I can't investigate a lot so :
This worked for me, basically never write a closure function in the routes file !

I will update if I dug deeper and found a real solution but I solved my problem with this now
Just creating a test function into the controller and that's it

Answer (score 2):

`php artisan optimize` did it for me!